# The converse of some theorems about Minkowski functional

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

(From Lax's functional analysis)

Let p denote a positive homogeneous subadditive function defined on a linear space $X$ over the reals.

(1)The set of points $x$ satisfying $p(x) < 1$ is a convex set S of X, and $0$ is an interior point of it (i.e. for any y $\in$ X, there is an $\theta$, $0 + t y\in S $ for all real $t$, $|t|<\theta$);

(2)The set of points $x$ satisfying $p(x) \le 1$ is a convex set of X.

PS: It's easy to prove the convexity. However, I have some problems to prove the second statement in (1), and I am wondering why (2) cannot get the conclusion that  $0$ is an interior point.

Comment: What is the topology? The question does not make sense unless there is some connection between $p$ and the topology.

Comment: There's no assumptions about topology. You can find the theorems listed above on Page 22 in Lax's book.@Kavi

Comment: What do you mean by 'interior'. You are missing some part of the text so this question cannot be answered.

Comment: I‘ve added the definition of  'interior point' to the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $p(y) >0$ and $p(-y) >0$. Then $p(0+ty) \leq p(0)+p(ty)=0+|t| p(\pm y) <1$ if $|t| <\frac 1 {|p(y)|}$ and $|t| <\frac 1 {|p(-y)|}$. So $0$ is an  interior point.  I will leave the cases $p(y)=0$ and $p(-y)=0$ to you. ($0$ is also an interior point of $\{x: p(x) \leq 1\}$)

Comment: I agree with you. It was a little confusing when I first saw these two statements in Lax's functional analysis, and I thought there might be some point I had missed. Thanks for your solution. It's a great help.